# How do you render just the reflections of smoke?

Tags: rendering, smoke-simulation, effects, mantaflow

How would you go about rendering just the reflection of smoke? Im trying have smoke reflect off of text but not appear anywhere else?

Answer (score 0):

For your smoke domain, in Object Properties/Visibility/Ray visibility, disable Camera:
[image]